# Running Python in 32 bit mode for Mac

Tags: python, pygame, 32bit-64bit

All of the forums I'm finding for this issue are dated/ not working. I need to download 2.7 since that's the version my school computers use, but I can't change my Python version into 32 bit! (required for pygame) I've read like 100 forums.

Comment: 2.7 is not the latest version PyGame runs on; it works on 3.2+ as well. There may not be binary installer packages for it for Python 3.x on Mac, but since you can't use the binary installer packages anyway (because of this 32-bit problem), who cares?

Comment: Also, you don't need to download 2.7; your Mac already came with 2.7 pre-installed. And if you look at the download links, notice that the ones for OS X 10.6 and 10.7 (the latest ones they have) are for "apple supplied python", so unless you're using 10.5 or earlier, you don't want to install another one.

Comment: how to do I run 2.7.5 on mac, @abarnert

Comment: From the Terminal, just type `python` and that's 2.7. You'll see the banner saying "Python 2.7.2" (Snow Leopard/Lion/Mountain Lion) or "Python 2.7.5" (Mavericks).

Comment: OK, does that convince you that you don't need to download 2.7?

Comment: @abarnert ok so I typed `Python 2.7.5` it gave me this `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '2.7.5': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Why did you type `Python 2.7.5`? Just type `python`. You already did that, and it worked.

Comment: But meanwhile, if your Python is in /Library/Frameworks rather than /System/Library/Frameworks, that means you _already_ installed an extra 2.7 from somewhere, so now you have _two_ of them. This is going to cause confusion.

Comment: Sorry for being kinda so... new but when I type Python it displays that message but pythong 2.7.5 in 32 bit mode didn't open or anything.

Comment: ok I'll uninstall a few things and get back to you.

Comment: The reason their binary packages, and instructions for them, are so bad is that packaging binary Python modules for Mac is (a) hard, and (b) a bad idea. I don't know why they seem to recommend them. I just install pygame with pip, the same way I do with any other package, the same way I do on any other (non-windows) platform, and it works fine. You do need the install the prereqs first (SDL and PortAudio), but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way to run a fat binary in 32-bit mode on OS X is the [`arch`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/arch/) command:

```
arch -32 python
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't actually work with Apple's pre-installed Python, or with python.org builds! You can verify this yourself:

```
$ arch -32 python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize.bit_length()
63
```

You just ran the launcher in 32-bit mode, which then ran the real Python executable in 64-bit mode.

---

So, where's that real Python executable?

Well, if you stuck with Apple's Python, there's a well-known location for it:

```
$ arch -32 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize.bit_length()
31
```

Tada!

You will probably want to make a shell alias, wrapper script, or other means to make that easier so you don't have to type that whole monster line all the time.

---

If you installed an additional Python 2.7 alongside the one Apple already gave you, there are many different places it could be. It *might* be the same path with the `/System` knocked off the front, but it might not. The safest thing to do here is to uninstall that extra Python and just stick with the one that Apple gave you. Especially since the latest [PyGame downloads](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) for 1.9.2pre are for Apple-supplied Python, and won't help with a different Python anyway.

Yes, there's also the "pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg". But Python.org hasn't shipped that version in years; the current 2.7 package is for 10.6+, not 10.3+, so that package isn't going to work for you anyway unless you can dig up an ancient installer.

---

Personally, I wouldn't use their binary installers in the first place. They're a huge mess, they're not kept up to date, the instructions for them don't match the packages…

Instead, just do it the same way you do any other Python package: install the prerequisites (either from an http://sdl.org installer, or by using a package manager like Homebrew to `brew install ddl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi`), then just `sudo pip install pygame`.